# XSLT templates with param

Tags: templates, xslt, xalan

**Setup:** Apache, Xalan 2.7.1, xslt 1.0
**Input:** 3 Files xml aprox. 750mb

Given a `template with param` called by its name, is there a performance gain from passing current context by param or by using the `current()` function from inside the template?

```
<xsl:call-template name="one">
    <xsl:with-param name="context" select = "." />
</xsl:call-template>

    <!-- OR -->

<xsl:call-template name="two"/>

<xsl:template name="one"> 
    <xsl:param name = "context" />      
    <xsl:value-of select="$context/something"/>     
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="two">   
    <xsl:value-of select="current()/somthing"/>     
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you are interested in answering performance questions then you need to use a particular XSLT processor and measure the performance.

Comment: I would think that if there is a difference, it's likely to be imperceptibly small, but the only way to find out is to measure it, as Martin says. Do you actually have a performance problem? If you have, then changing this code isn't the solution. If you haven't, then why are you asking the question?

Comment: I can't test or measure or do anything that would unnecesserly disturb the server. Transformation is rather massive.

Comment: If you can't take measurements then forget all thoughts of performance tuning. Measurement is at the heart of all performance work.

Comment: I trying to gain some boost, even seconds are fine to reduce server task q load.

Comment: Well thank you dr. Kay I'll keep that in mind. I'll try to duplicate the enviroment and do some testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Michael Kay adviced I did some testing, and **with-param** seems to be slightly faster than the **current()** function.

Test Input: `xml file` (`540 mb`), with 3 levels deep `root/l1/l2/l3`

Test ran 8 times on apache Xalan 2.7.1

[image]

**with-param** shows aprox. 20% better performance